# Subdomain Creation in Amazon EC2 using Nginx Server

Tags: nginx, ruby, amazon-ec2

I am using amazon ec2.... My app is written in Ruby on Rails. I am using Nginx Server. How can I create sub-domain and automate it when a user registers like  http://user.mywebsite.com?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this, you need access to your DNS server - either through your domain hoster or whatever you use to manage your DNS zone.
The easiest would be to have a wildcard DNS entry (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_DNS_record). This will send all subdomains .yourdomain.tld to your EC2 instance(s). Once you have that, you only need some logic in you application which does whatever you want if a valid subdomain (say: user name) is used or redirect to your landing page or an error page if the subdomain is unknown.

Ah, one little thing i sleft. Your webserver has to accept the subdomains. If you use Apache httpd, the following line in your VirtualHost configuration will do the trick:

```
ServerAlias *.yourdomain.tld
```

For nginx the configuration should look like this:

```
server {
  server_name *.yourdomain.tld
  ...
}
```

Comment: thank you.. but initially i just want to change http://example.com/user to http://user.example.com... moreover i am using nginx server. Is there any trick to do this..??

Comment: It is the same, just the nginx configuration differs :)